# How to place the table in the center of the page, and have no more space on the right?

Tags: tables, floats

How to place the table in the center of the page.
I would like to have the table positioned in the center.
This is the code

```
\begin{table}[H]
\checkoddpage
  \edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\scalebox{0.77}{
\begin{tabular}{ c|l|c|c }
\bottomrule
\rowcolor{bluee}
Codice ISCO08 & Titolo dell'occupazione                                                                        & Telelavoro   tecnico & Interazione   sociale \\\midrule
111           & Legislatori e alti   funzionari                                                                & 1.00                 & 0.68                  \\
112           & Amministratori delegati e dirigenti                                                            & 1.00                 & 0.69                  \\
131           & Responsabili della produzione nel settore dell'agricoltura, della   silvicoltura e della pesca & 0.00                 & 0.62                  \\
141           & Gestori di hotel e   ristoranti                                                                & 0.97                 & 0.63                   \\
216           & Architetti, progettisti, geometri e progettisti                                                & 0.38                 & 0.36                   \\
221           & Medici                                                                                         & 0.39                 & 0.79                  \\
225           & Veterinari                                                                                     & 0.00                 & 0.64                  \\
231           & Insegnanti universitari e di istruzione superiore                                              & 0.49                 & 0.80                  \\
233           & Insegnanti dell’istruzione secondaria                                                          & 1.00                 & 0.77                  \\
241           & Professionisti della finanza                                                                   & 1.00                 & 0.46                   \\
251           & Sviluppatori e analisti di software e applicazioni                                             & 1.00                 & 0.46                   \\
264           & Autori, giornalisti   e linguisti                                                              & 1.00                 & 0.43                   \\
332           & Agenti e broker di vendita e acquisto                                                          & 1.00                 & 0.66                   \\
342           & Operatori sportivi e di fitness                                                                & 0.04                 & 0.67                   \\
412           & Segretari (generali)                                                                           & 1.00                 & 0.44                  \\
511           & Assistenti di viaggio, conduttori e guide                                                      & 0.73                 & 0.78                  \\
512           & Cuochi                                                                                         & 0.00                 & 0.48                   \\
521           & Venditori di strada e di mercato                                                               & 0.00                 & 0.84                   \\
723           & Meccanici e riparatori di macchinari                                                           & 0.00                 & 0.33                   \\
951           & Lavoratori della strada e dei servizi connessi                                                 & 0.00                 & 0.43              \\ 
\bottomrule     
\end{tabular}}
}
\caption[Valori di Telelavoro tecnico e di Interazione sociale per alcuni codici ISCO-3digit]{\small{Valori di Telelavoro tecnico e di Interazione sociale per alcuni codici ISCO-3digit}}
\label{tab:mb} 
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your table currently  appears to be quite a lot wider thatn the available textwidth. Personally, I suggest adjusting the table's width to be equal to the textwidth. Also, avoid rescaling tables as this will lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout the document.

Comment: if you must scale (but really that should be the last resort, and even then don't do it) delete `\makebox`  that is doing nothing useful and replace `\scalebox` by `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}` so it is textwidth wide. beware spaces from ends of lines `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\scalebox{0.77}{` adds 1.77 word inter-word spaces to the left of the table.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why do you use `\bottomrule` instead of `\toprule` at the top of the table?

Answer (score 6):

Here's another `tabularx`-based solution. It uses variable-width X-type columns, to make the 2nd column more than twice as wide as columns 1, 3, and 4. It also performs automatic hanging identation on the contents of the cells in column 2. Finally, it omits the first two horizontal rules, as there's no need for them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ C{0.5} L{2.35} C{0.55} C{0.6} }
\rowcolor{LightBlue}
Codice ISCO08 & Titolo dell'occupazione & Telelavoro tecnico & Interazione sociale \\ 
\addlinespace 
111 & Legislatori e alti funzionari                     & 1.00       & 0.68    \\
112 & Amministratori delegati e dirigenti               & 1.00       & 0.69    \\
131 & Responsabili della produzione nel settore dell'agricoltura,
      della silvicoltura e della pesca                  & 0.00       & 0.62    \\
141 & Gestori di hotel e ristoranti                     & 0.97       & 0.63    \\
216 & Architetti, progettisti, geometri e progettisti   & 0.38       & 0.36    \\
221 & Medici                                            & 0.39       & 0.79    \\
225 & Veterinari                                        & 0.00       & 0.64    \\
231 & Insegnanti universitari e di istruzione superiore & 0.49       & 0.80    \\
233 & Insegnanti dell’istruzione secondaria             & 1.00       & 0.77    \\
241 & Professionisti della finanza                      & 1.00       & 0.46    \\
251 & Sviluppatori e analisti di software e applicazioni& 1.00       & 0.46    \\
264 & Autori, giornalisti e linguisti                   & 1.00       & 0.43    \\
332 & Agenti e broker di vendita e acquisto             & 1.00       & 0.66    \\
342 & Operatori sportivi e di fitness                   & 0.04       & 0.67    \\
412 & Segretari (generali)                              & 1.00       & 0.44    \\
511 & Assistenti di viaggio, conduttori e guide         & 0.73       & 0.78    \\
512 & Cuochi                                            & 0.00       & 0.48    \\
521 & Venditori di strada e di mercato                  & 0.00       & 0.84    \\
723 & Meccanici e riparatori di macchinari              & 0.00       & 0.33    \\
951 & Lavoratori della strada e dei servizi connessi    & 0.00       & 0.43    \\ 
\bottomrule     
\end{tabularx}
\caption[Valori di Telelavoro tecnico e di Interazione sociale per alcuni codici 
ISCO-3digit]{Valori di Telelavoro tecnico e di Interazione sociale per alcuni 
codici ISCO-3digit}
\label{tab:mb} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to scale this at all. Note I left in the vertical rules but you are using `booktabs` (although you did not say) which does not support vertical rules, by design,

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\definecolor{bluee}{rgb}{.5,.5,1}
\newcommand\hd[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]%[H]
%\checkoddpage
%  \edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}
% no!!  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
% no!! \scalebox{0.77}{

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|X|c|c}
\bottomrule
\rowcolor{bluee}
\hd{Codice\\ISCO08}&
Titolo dell'occupazione&
\hd{Telelavoro\\tecnico}&
\hd{Interazione\\sociale}\\
\midrule
111           & Legislatori e alti   funzionari                                                                & 1.00                 & 0.68                  \\
112           & Amministratori delegati e dirigenti                                                            & 1.00                 & 0.69                  \\
131           & Responsabili della produzione nel settore dell'agricoltura, della   silvicoltura e della pesca & 0.00                 & 0.62                  \\
141           & Gestori di hotel e   ristoranti                                                                & 0.97                 & 0.63                   \\
216           & Architetti, progettisti, geometri e progettisti                                                & 0.38                 & 0.36                   \\
221           & Medici                                                                                         & 0.39                 & 0.79                  \\
225           & Veterinari                                                                                     & 0.00                 & 0.64                  \\
231           & Insegnanti universitari e di istruzione superiore                                              & 0.49                 & 0.80                  \\
233           & Insegnanti dell’istruzione secondaria                                                          & 1.00                 & 0.77                  \\
241           & Professionisti della finanza                                                                   & 1.00                 & 0.46                   \\
251           & Sviluppatori e analisti di software e applicazioni                                             & 1.00                 & 0.46                   \\
264           & Autori, giornalisti   e linguisti                                                              & 1.00                 & 0.43                   \\
332           & Agenti e broker di vendita e acquisto                                                          & 1.00                 & 0.66                   \\
342           & Operatori sportivi e di fitness                                                                & 0.04                 & 0.67                   \\
412           & Segretari (generali)                                                                           & 1.00                 & 0.44                  \\
511           & Assistenti di viaggio, conduttori e guide                                                      & 0.73                 & 0.78                  \\
512           & Cuochi                                                                                         & 0.00                 & 0.48                   \\
521           & Venditori di strada e di mercato                                                               & 0.00                 & 0.84                   \\
723           & Meccanici e riparatori di macchinari                                                           & 0.00                 & 0.33                   \\
951           & Lavoratori della strada e dei servizi connessi                                                 & 0.00                 & 0.43              \\ 
\bottomrule     
\end{tabularx}
\caption[Valori di Telelavoro tecnico e di Interazione sociale per alcuni codici ISCO-3digit]{\small{Valori di Telelavoro tecnico e di Interazione sociale per alcuni codici ISCO-3digit}}
\label{tab:mb} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```